# How do I set up two-way databinding inside an ng-repeat that iterates over an array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using angularjs to my webapp but i can't understand how tu pass an array to ng-model inside an ng-repeat. this is my code

```
<div>
<table class="table table-hover" width="100%">
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
        <td width="33%">{{item.name}}</td>
        <td width="66%">
            <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" name="{{item.price}}" value="{{item.price}}" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="save()">Save</button>
```

As you can see the save button is external to form. I'd like to add an ng-model to input tag but it has to be an array cause it is inside an ng-repat. How can i do this? thanx

Comment: question is not clear ??

Comment: i have to pass te values of input boxes generated by ng-repeat to js controller on click button. when i click to button angular calls save function inside controller. how can i retrive the values of all input boxes? i suppose the only solution is to use ng-model in input tag but it has to be an array not a single value

Comment: Do you want the array to be different from your items array?

Comment: did you try `ng-model="item.price"`?

Comment: i resolve. it is ng-mode="item.price" and in the controller simply call items.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding an add function in your controller that looks like this i

```
$scope.add = function(){
  $scope.items.push({price:''})
}
```

and add a button next to save like

```
<button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
```